# Error in running Scapy Sniff function in python2,3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, scapy

i wrote this program to sniff arp packets in the network and print there source address. The code is as follows:
(this is just modify sample source a little bit about amazon dash button sniping packet )

```
from scapy.all import *

import urllib

global flag

def arp_display(pkt):


if pkt[ARP].op == 1: #who-has (request)

#if pkt[ARP].psrc == '0.0.0.0': # ARP Probe

  if pkt[ARP].hwsrc == '0c:47:c3:e6:c5:b7': # Energizier

    print ("Pushed Energizier")

    if (flag == NULL) or (flag == 0):

       url = url + "LED=0"

       req = urllib2.Request(url)

       response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

       flag = 1

       print ( "send signal")

    else :

       url = url + "LED=1"

       req = urllib2.Request(url)

       response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

       flag = 0


  elif pkt[ARP].hwsrc == 'a4:af:66:df:9e:45': # Elements

    print ("Pushed Elements")

  else:

    print ("ARP Probe from unknown device: " + pkt[ARP].hwsrc)



print ( sniff(prn=arp_display, filter="arp", store=0, count=10,lfilter=lambda pkt: ARP in pkt) )
```

error message is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/share/Web/python/dash_check.py", line 54, in <module>
print ( sniff(prn=arp_display, filter="arp", store=0, 
count=10,lfilter=lambda pkt: ARP in pkt) )
File "/opt/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 620, in sniffr = prn(p)
File "/share/Web/python/dash_check.py", line 21, in arp_display
if (flag == NULL) or (flag == 0):
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment
```

really i don't know why print out error message like this

Comment: you are using `flag` before it has a value in the `if` statement in line 21. You need to assign a value, or even `None`, to the `flag` variable before you come to that `if` statement.

Comment: Please edit your question's title if you can because your problem do not relate with `scrapy`.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to access and modify a global variable in your function. But as you are assigning this `flag` variable within the function's scope, as in:

```
flag = 1
```

and

```
flag = 0
```

`flag` is assumed as a local variable and it shadows the same named global variable in the outer scope. Take a look at here: [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

This is a minimal example of what is happening with your code:

```
flag = 0
def func():
    if flag==0:
        print("flag is 0")
        flag = 1
```

calling `func()` will raise the same error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'flag' referenced before assignment
```

The solution for this is to use the `global` keyword for modifying the global variable in local scope. Like this:

```
flag = 0
def func():
    global flag
    if flag==0:
        print("flag is 0")
        flag = 1
```

Please check the link with the answer for better understanding.